# Selecting rows of a Pandas dataframe based on a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that only have two columns like this

```
          Timestamp       X
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00 18450
1   2017-01-01 00:10:00 13787
2   2017-01-01 00:20:00 3249
3   2017-01-01 00:30:00 44354
4   2017-01-01 00:40:00 50750
```

The Timestamp column is basically 10 minute separated ranging from start of the month to end. To create a sample the following code can be used.

```
l_data = pd.DataFrame()

l_data['Timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 00:00:00'), end=pd.Timestamp('2017-01-20 00:00:00'), freq='10T')
l_data['X'] = random.sample(range(0, 100000), len(l_data))
```

I have a dictionary with me like this

```
  {Timestamp('2017-01-18 01:37:19.160000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 01:37:29.520000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 01:41:04.880000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 01:41:10.280000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:33:52.800000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:00.040000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:02.120000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:50:00.040000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:50:02.120000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:00:00.040000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:00:02.120000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:01:50.760000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:20:22.760000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:25:20.760000'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:35:52.800000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:40:00.040000')}
```

The key in the dictionary is starting time and value is the ending time. I want to create a column named `L` based on this `dict` in `l_data`

If the time between key and value in `dict` is greater than 5 minute I have to mark the Timestamp that falls in that range in `l_data` as 1.

How to implement this in pandas in a straight forward way rather than using multiple loops.?

Expected output will look like this

```
126 1/18/2017 21:00 43401   0
127 1/18/2017 21:10 290     0
128 1/18/2017 21:20 92509   0
129 1/18/2017 21:30 64545   0
130 1/18/2017 21:40 47780   1
131 1/18/2017 21:50 53293   1
132 1/18/2017 22:00 45634   0
133 1/18/2017 22:10 51462   0
134 1/18/2017 22:20 44736   0
135 1/18/2017 22:30 11697   1
136 1/18/2017 22:40 82587   1
137 1/18/2017 22:50 76250   0
138 1/18/2017 23:00 33307   0
139 1/18/2017 23:10 25851   0
140 1/18/2017 23:20 71131   0
141 1/18/2017 23:30 88015   0
142 1/18/2017 23:40 45577   0
143 1/18/2017 23:50 76761   0
144 1/19/2017 0:00  45363   0
```

Only significant rows are shown

Comment: Can you please make an example with 5 rows instead of 5000? Then you could post the expected output and I could verify my answer before posting it.

Comment: 5 rows wont give the expected distribution of start and end times. That's why I went for 5000

Comment: How does this matter for the algorithm?

Comment: Sometimes start and end will lie within 10 mints range some times it will be between two timestamps.

Comment: Yes, ok, then make ten rows? :) Or as many as you need to fit all cases in.

Comment: reduced the number of rows

Comment: Thanks, if you give us the desired result now we're golden! (edit: I'll check back later, by I'm sure you'll have an answer by the pandas experts by then)

Comment: I really wish I could, but manual checking is taking hell lot of a time even for a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
d = { pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:45:02.120000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:50:29.040000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:51:02.120000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:52:00.040000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:52:02.120000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 22:57:59.760000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 23:41:52.800000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 23:43:00.040000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 23:44:52.800000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 23:50:30.040000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 01:10:32.800000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 01:11:30.040000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 01:40:32.800000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 01:55:30.040000'),
pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 01:57:32.800000'): pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 02:04:30.040000')}

l_data = pd.DataFrame()
l_data['Timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('2017-01-18 20:00:00'), 
                                    end=pd.Timestamp('2017-01-19 04:00:00'), freq='10T')
l_data['expected'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

```
#print (l_data)

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': list(d.keys()),'end': list(d.values())})
#fikter by 5 minutes
df = df[(df['end'] - df['start']) > pd.Timedelta(5*60, 's')]

#correct 1 minutes end time
s = df['end'].dt.floor('10T')
df['end1'] = s.where((df['end'] - s) < pd.Timedelta(60, 's'), s + pd.Timedelta(10*60, 's'))
print (df)
                    start                     end                end1
0 2017-01-18 21:45:02.120 2017-01-18 21:50:29.040 2017-01-18 21:50:00
1 2017-01-18 21:51:02.120 2017-01-18 22:52:00.040 2017-01-18 23:00:00
2 2017-01-18 22:52:02.120 2017-01-18 22:57:59.760 2017-01-18 23:00:00
4 2017-01-18 23:44:52.800 2017-01-18 23:50:30.040 2017-01-18 23:50:00
6 2017-01-19 01:40:32.800 2017-01-19 01:55:30.040 2017-01-19 02:00:00
7 2017-01-19 01:57:32.800 2017-01-19 02:04:30.040 2017-01-19 02:10:00

#for each group resample by 10min and add missimg datetimes
v = (df.reset_index()[['start','end1','index']]
       .melt('index')
       .set_index('value')
       .groupby('index')
       .resample('10T')['index']
       .ffill()
       .dropna()
       .index
       .get_level_values(1)
       .unique()
       )
#print (v)
```

---

```
l_data['L'] = l_data['Timestamp'].isin(v).astype(int)
print (l_data.head(20))
             Timestamp  expected  L
0  2017-01-18 20:00:00         0  0
1  2017-01-18 20:10:00         0  0
2  2017-01-18 20:20:00         0  0
3  2017-01-18 20:30:00         0  0
4  2017-01-18 20:40:00         0  0
5  2017-01-18 20:50:00         0  0
6  2017-01-18 21:00:00         0  0
7  2017-01-18 21:10:00         0  0
8  2017-01-18 21:20:00         0  0
9  2017-01-18 21:30:00         0  0
10 2017-01-18 21:40:00         0  0
11 2017-01-18 21:50:00         1  1
12 2017-01-18 22:00:00         1  1
13 2017-01-18 22:10:00         1  1
14 2017-01-18 22:20:00         1  1
15 2017-01-18 22:30:00         1  1
16 2017-01-18 22:40:00         1  1
17 2017-01-18 22:50:00         1  1
18 2017-01-18 23:00:00         1  1
19 2017-01-18 23:10:00         0  0
```

Comment: Give me some time to verify the result

Comment: @SreeramTP - sure, not sure about condition, noew i have less like 5 minutes, maybe need more - then change `<` to `>` in conditions.

Comment: Since `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:33:52.800000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:00.040000')` is more than 5 minutes i want the timestamp `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:00.040000')` marked as 1

Comment: oops, so not understand it. give me some time.

Comment: The conditions are if the value - key is more than 5 mints mark the time in `l_data` that corresponds to value. There may be samples like this `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:33:52.800000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:43:00.040000')`. The difference is more than 5 mints but value is past `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:00.040000')` then mark `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:50:00.040000')`

Comment: @SreeramTP - so if `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:33:52.800000'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:43:00.040000')` then need set `1` to data between `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:33:52.800000') - 5minutes: Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:43:00.040000') + 5 minutes`  ?

Comment: It must be set to the nearest 10 mint timestamp from the value. higher always. Something like ceil

Comment: @SreeramTP - OK, so if  so if `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:33:50'): Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:10')` what values are selected? what range?

Comment: eventhough the next highest 10 mint timestamp of `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:10')` will be `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:50:00')` it is less than 1 mint apart from  `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:00')`  so `Timestamp('2017-01-18 21:40:00')`  will be marked

Comment: @SreeramTP - I dont understand, then why start time is important?

Comment: Actually the key-value is a time in with the event is occured. It only matters if the duration of the event is 5min+. The data i will be storing will be 10min sperated. I want to show that event info in the data. Since the resolution is very different I want to indicate in which 10 min slice the event have occured

Comment: Si first is necessary difference between value and key for each item of dict. If higher like 5 minutes, then is necessary check if value is between timestamp  column + 10 minutes ? I understand it correct ?

Comment: @SreeramTP - sorry, meeting. So I changed conditions by `m1 = (df['end'] - df['start']) < pd.Timedelta(5 * 60, unit='s')`
`m2 = (df['end'] + pd.Timedelta(10 * 60, unit='s') < df['Timestamp'])` and it set all values to 1, is it correct?

Comment: can you update your code with this code and new output.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183700/discussion-between-sreeram-tp-and-jezrael).

Comment: @SreeramTP - I was offline. Is possible some way it explain more? Because I am lost, sorry.

Comment: @ jezrael I have explained in the chat. Please see it

Comment: it is perfect. Thanks alot. You are awesome.